# Efficient recoding of numeric variables into a factor in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr, tidyverse

In recoding values of numeric variables like `var1` below into character values, sometimes there is an easy patter. For example, suppose numeric values `1:4` in `var1` need to be recoded as `LETTERS[27-(4:1)]`, respectively.

In such situations, is it possible to avoid writing `var1 = recode(var1,`1`="W",`2`="X",`3`="Y",`4`="Z")` and instead loop the recoding?

```
library(tidyverse)

(dat <- data.frame(var1 = rep(1:4,2), id = 1:8))

mutate(dat, var1 = recode(var1,`1`="W",`2`="X",`3`="Y",`4`="Z")) # This works but can we 
                                                                 # loop it as well?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a vectorized approach, no loops necessary. `tail` and base subsetting with `[` will do the trick here.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% mutate(var1=tail(LETTERS, max(var1))[var1] %>% as.factor)
  var1 id
1    W  1
2    X  2
3    Y  3
4    Z  4
5    W  5
6    X  6
7    Y  7
8    Z  8
```

**data**

```
dat <- data.frame(var1 = rep(1:4,2), id = 1:8)
```

**data2**

```
dat2 <- data.frame(var1 = c(2,1,3,1,4:1), id = 1:8))

  var1 id
1    2  1
2    1  2
3    3  3
4    1  4
5    4  5
6    3  6
7    2  7
8    1  8
```

**output2**

```
  var1 id
1    X  1
2    W  2
3    Y  3
4    W  4
5    Z  5
6    Y  6
7    X  7
8    W  8
```

Comment: This is not dependent on how elements of `var1` are ordered, right? For example, `var1` could have been: `var1 = c(2,1,3,1,4:1)`?

Comment: The answer is consistent with any order of var1. See the updated answer with this new example data

Comment: Please mind that it will only work if the levels of var1 are a sequence of integers with min==1, regardless of the order

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% mutate(var1 = LETTERS[length(LETTERS)-max(var1) + var1])

#  var1 id
#1    W  1
#2    X  2
#3    Y  3
#4    Z  4
#5    W  5
#6    X  6
#7    Y  7
#8    Z  8
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also just use the labels argument of factor()

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(var1 = rep(1:4,2), id = 1:8) %>% 
  mutate(var1 = factor(var1, labels = tail(LETTERS, 4)))
dat

  var1 id
1    W  1
2    X  2
3    Y  3
4    Z  4
5    W  5
6    X  6
7    Y  7
8    Z  8
```